# Mathematical Analysis I by Zorich: show $f^{-1}(f(A)) \supset A$, $f(f^{-1}(B^{'})) \subset B'$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I ask someone to check if my proof is correct. I'm self-studying Mathematical analysis by Zorich and the book doesn't have any answers, so I would like to catch any logical mistakes early on. Very not sure about the second question in particular.

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a map from $X$ to $Y$. Show that for any $A \subset X$ and any $B^{'}\subset Y$:

1. $f^{-1}(f(A)) \supset A$
2. $f(f^{-1}(B^{'})) \subset B'$

1} Let $x \in A$. Then $f(x) \in f(A)$. Then $f^{-1}(f(x))=x \in f^{-1}(f(A))$. So $A \subset f^{-1}(f(A))$.

2} Let $y \in f(f^{-1}(B^{'}))$. Then $f^{-1}(y) \in f^{-1}(B^{'})$. Then $f(f^{-1}(y))=y  \in f(f^{-1}(B^{'}))=B^{'}.$ So $f(f^{-1}(B^{'})) \subset B^{'}$

1_edited) Let $x \in A$. Then $f(x) \in f(A)$. Then $x \in f^{-1}(f(x)) \subset f^{-1}(f(A))$. So $A \subset f^{-1}(f(A))$

2_edited) Let $y∈f(f^{−1}(B′))$. Then $f^{−1}(y) \subset f^{−1}(B′)$. Then $f(f^{−1}(y)) \subset f(f^{−1}(B′))=B′.$ So $f(f^{−1}(B′))⊂B′$.

Comment: $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ is not always true, but you don't need it. Enough is $x\in f^{-1}(f(x)) \subset f^{-1}(f(A))$.

Comment: For second: $f^{-1}(y)$ can be set, so $\in$ to right of it is not always correct. Again, you don't need it..

Comment: @zkutch Thank you! I have corrected my answers to reflect your comments. Did I understand correctly? And also, does $f(f^{-1}(B'))$ in fact equal $B^{'}$?

Comment: Wrote answer with little remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In second case of edition you use $f(f^{−1}(B′))=B′$ to proof $f(f^{−1}(B′))\subset B′$, so it's a bit of a vicious circle.

Let me suggest to use exactly definitions from page $16$ (Vladimir A. Zorich - Mathematical Analysis I-Springer (2016)):

$$f(A)=\{ y: (\exists x)(x\in A \land y=f(x))  \} \\ 
 f^{-1}(B) = \{x:f(x)\in B\} $$

Step by step: $$y\in f(f^{−1}(B′)) \Leftrightarrow  (\exists x)\Big(x\in f^{−1}(B′) \land y=f(x)\Big) \Leftrightarrow \\ \Leftrightarrow (\exists x)\Big(f(x) \in B′ \land y=f(x)\Big) \Rightarrow y \in B$$.

**Addition 1.**
And now  your question in comment about is always $\boldsymbol f\pmb (\pmb f^{\pmb − \pmb 1}\pmb (\pmb B′\pmb ) \pmb )\pmb =\pmb B′$ or not. Answer is, that for every [surjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) function we have this equality for $\forall B' \subset Y$, where $Y$ is range (exactly it is target, page 76, from Bourbaki below) of $f$. To prove this, formally we need second half $B\subset f(f^{−1}(B′))$:
So, let's take $y\in B$. Because $f$ is surjection, then we have existence of some $A$ from domain, such that for $x\in A$ we have $f(x) = y \in B′$, for every element $y\in B′$ i.e. $y\in f(A)$ and for $A$ exactly holds definition of $f^{−1}(B′)$, so $y\in f(f^{−1}(B′))$.

**Addition 2.** Definition of surjection appeared in book Nicolas Bourbaki - Theory of Sets-Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg (2004), which is known for  causing big burbakophilia and Big burbakofobiya, on page 84 and property from your question is discussing on page 85. For the sake of completeness, let's also add that the concept of [injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) (mathematical, not medicine), which appears also on the page 84. The property $\boldsymbol f^{\pmb − \pmb 1}\pmb (\pmb f\pmb (\pmb A \pmb )\pmb )\pmb =\pmb A$, for any $A$ from domain (exactly it is source, page 76) of $f$, just causes the injection (page 86). Let me say, that it is very nicely noticed what the permutation of symbols $f$ and $f^{−1}$ gives. By the way, if they holds both, then we get the well-known [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) property defined on the page 84.

Answer (score 1):

1. Let $x \in A$. Then $f(x) \in f(A)$. Therefore, $x \in f^{-1}(f(x))\subset f^{-1}(f(A))$. We have $A \subset f^{-1}(f(A))$.
2. Let $y \in f(f^{-1}(B′))$. Then there exists $z \in f^{-1}(B′)$ such that $f(z) = y$. Since $z \in f^{-1}(B′)$, we have $y=f(z) \in B′$. Therefore, $f(f^{−1}(B′))⊂B′$.